# Delay between each integration test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'd like to inquire, whether it is possible to add a delay after each test? For example, I have **Test1**, **Test2** and **Test3**. I understand, that they'll run in a random order, but is it possible to make something like that: **Test1** -> 1 second delay -> **Test2** -> 1 second delay -> **Test3**. Didn't find any topics related to that.

I'm **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting**

Comment: Is `Thread.Sleep()` an option?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub , I thought `Thread.Sleep()` was a bad choice as the program becomes unresponsive until the time is elapsed. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Normally people try to eliminate delays from their test runs.  What motivates you to introduce these delays?  Maybe the reason behind this is something that should be taken care of instead...

Answer (score 0):

Try ordered tests: 
I guess what you are looking for is to execute one test after another.
Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704.aspx

Comment: I get an exception "Suspend of Service", as I'm using a WEB Face Recognition API. I've made an assumption, that I may exceed 10QPS, so it throws that exception. I'll try your solution, thanks :)